# Facebook development

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would lile to develop interactions with facebook. I see there are a lot of questions on the subject but I have no idea where to start. Could someone kindly point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: If people are going to downvote, can you at least tell the person asking why you did so?  He/she needs to know how he can improve the question.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a substitute for making your own survey of the resources, nor is it for asking vague recommendation questions.  There's no indication here that the poster has spent any time reading FB's developer pages or looking for sample FB app projects to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the question is a reasonable one; much of the documentation is oriented to somebody who is already up to their eyeballs in Facebook integration.

The tutorials are not bad. E.g. if you have an iPad/iPhone and a web server, start with http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/ and go slowly through it. Even there you will find that it isn't newbie-friendly, but if you can successfully get a few examples going it may get your confidence up, and you can try to navigate something more complex.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of great resources [here](http://developers.facebook.com/) including a getting started section.  Good luck!